# Select two columns from same table with different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two select statements and I want to generate two columns, one from each statement side by side using these two select statements inside a single select statement

**Query 1**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CASE_ID 
 from t1 
 WHERE MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-56 
                       AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-49
```

```
CASE_ID
12
13
14
15
17
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE_ID
from t1 
WHERE MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-49 
                      AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-42
```

```
CASE_ID
45
98
67
90
76
82
61
```

Final Output should be something like:

```
C1   C2
12   45
13   98
14   67
15   90
17   76
     82
     61
```

Could anyone tell me how to do to so?

Thank You.

---

**Update**

One of the query I tried from the answers :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
             case when 
                MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 56 
                                  AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 49
               then CASE_ID 
             end as c1,
        DISTINCT 
               case when 
                  MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-49  
                                    AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-42 
                  then CASE_ID 
               end as c2
from t1 
WHERE MODIFIED_DATE 
         BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 56 
             AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 42
```

And I am getting ORA-00936: missing expression. Could anyone tell me the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL and/or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Sorry for that, in a hurry actually 

Comment: Edit your question when you are not in a hurry, and you'll get better answeres. Your queries don't make sense; `FROM t1 AND [condition]`? What does this mean? I'm sure the last bit is supposed to be a `where`, but where is your `group by`? Without it you can't get the results you say you get.

Comment: Sure, I will make the changes.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is NOT a function. `COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE_ID))`is the same as `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE_ID)`...

Comment: Do you have any relation between `col1` and `col2` Example does the value `45` for `col2` come only at `col1` value `12`

Comment: @sql_dummy , There is no relation between col1 and col2. They are two independent results.

Comment: I posted some solution, check if that what you want

Comment: `distinct` always applies to all columns in a select list. You can't have two `distinct` keywords in a regular select list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a filtered aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
             case when 
                MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 56 
                                  AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 49
               then CASE_ID 
             end) as c1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT 
               case when 
                  MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-49  
                                    AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-42 
                  then CASE_ID 
               end) as c2
from t1 
WHERE MODIFIED_DATE 
         BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 56 
             AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 42
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause now needs to cover both intervals.

Comment: Removed the COUNT function and wanted to print the DISTINCT CASE_ID,
Giving ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: @KetulPatani: you need to edit your question and show the new query if you have an error.

Comment: @KetulPatani: `distinct` always applies to all columns in a select list. You can't have two `distinct` keywords that are outside of an aggregate function.

Comment: How to add default kind of condition in the above case if no case is satisfied ?

Comment: @KetulPatani: use an `ELSE`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation between `col1` and `col2` , but you just want to display them side by side you can do as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE_ID) ,NULL 
  from t1 
  AND MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-56 
                   AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-49 
 union
 SELECT NULL, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE_ID) 
 from t1 
 AND MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-49 
                  AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-42
```

The output put woul look something like:

```
  C1   C2  
  12   NULL
  13   NULL
  .    NULL
  .    NULL
  NULL  45
  NULL  98
  NULL   .
  NULL   .
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you ?

```
  with w_q1 as (
           select case_id, row_number() over (order by modified_date) rid
              from (
                 SELECT DISTINCT CASE_ID
                    from t1 
                 WHERE MODIFIED_DATE 
                    BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 56 
                       AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 49
                 )
           ),
     w_q2 as (
           select case_id, row_number() over (order by modified_date) rid
              from (
                 SELECT DISTINCT CASE_ID
                    from t1 
                 WHERE MODIFIED_DATE 
                    BETWEEN TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 49
                       AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD') - 42
                   )
           )
  select w_q1.case_id, w_q2.case_id
    from w_q1
     full outer join w_q2
       on w_q1.rid = w_q2.rid
  /
```

It just takes your two "seperate" results, assigns a sort of "row id" to them, and uses that to join them ... using a full outer join to ensure nothing gets chopped off.

Comment: It works fine.
But what if I want to increase the columns here? What's work around with **rid** ?

Comment: rid is just the alias. I'm using `row_number` analytic function to assign numbers, starting with 1, to each record. That gives me "something" to join on, so I can artificially link the records side by side. Unfortunately, adding a third column becomes very clunky, you'd add a new `w_q3` query, and then tweak the final query. Not very pretty ... to be honest. Why are you trying to do this? How many columns do you need to handle ?

Comment: I would go upto some 8 columns. I am just distributing case_id with respect to modified_date.